# Why Vbs show this message

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wsh

This code work fine

```
set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
eAppData = oshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
wscript.echo Appdata
oshell.run(Appdata & "\Test.bat"),0,False
```

This .vbs in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

But when windows start show this message why ?

[image]

The `Test.bat` is in `%appdata%\Test.bat`

Comment: By default the .vbs file will be executed with the help of wscript.exe file.in such case if you use `wscript.echo` you will be getting messagebox.if you want to print the output in console then you need to run your file using cscript.exe <path to .vbs file>

Comment: So this was the problem all along? You didn't want the pop up to appear? Next time be more descriptive with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And when you get rid of this line : `wscript.echo Appdata`

This code will come like that if you don't want to display this message again

```
set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
AppData = oshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
oshell.run(Appdata & "\Test.bat"),0,False
```

Comment: @checkmate You are welcome anytime bro ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `wscript.echo Appdata`, which will cause this box to pop open containing the shown folder path.